# Facebook example not working in Connect-auth/Express

Tags: node.js, connect, express

I am following the example at [facebook Connect-auth exemple](https://github.com/ciaranj/connect-auth/wiki/Express---Facebook-example-%28with-additional-cunning-sign-in-page-redirect-logic%29). I don't understand how to get this example working.

In this snippet of code taken from the previous link:

```
// Method to handle a sign-in with a specified method type, and a url to go back to ...
app.get('/signin', function(req,res) {
  req.authenticate([req.param('method')], function(error, authenticated) { 
    if(authenticated ) {
      res.end("<html><h1>Hello Facebook user:" + JSON.stringify( req.getAuthDetails() ) + ".</h1></html>");
    }
    else {
      res.end("<html><h1>Facebook authentication failed: " + error + " </h1></html>");
    }
   });
});
```

I do not understand what this does `[req.param('method')]` mean? It it hard to understand how `connect-auth` and facebook work together. I keep getting authentication failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `authenticate` is an array of authentication strategies to try, in this example the `req.param['method']` is set in the URL (`var sign_in_link` further down in the code) to "facebook" which matches the one and only authentication strategy initialized in the `use`.

Comment: I could not make it work either, always get Facebook authentication failed.